# Pagenumbering on chapter pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

As part of a recent project, I want to have even and odd pagenumbering, as the document is to be printed double sided. I have added even and odd pagenumbering, which works as intended, however on every page containing a chapter or part header, the page number is centered rather than on the left or right.

The documentclass is:[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,openright]{book}
```

And the headers and footers are:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[lo,le]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from p. 7 of the user guide of the `fancyhdr` package:

> Some LaTeX commands, like `\chapter`, use the `\thispagestyle` command to automatically switch
>   to the `plain` page style, thus ignoring the page style currently in effect. To customize even such
>   pages you must redefine the `plain` pagestyle. As we indicated before you could do this by defining
>   the `\ps@plain` command, but `fancyhdr` gives you an easier way with the `\fancypagestyle` 
>   command. This command can be used to redefine existing pagestyles (like `plain`) or to define new
>   ones, e.g. if part of your document is to use a different pagestyle. This command has two 
>   parameters: one is the name of the pagestyle to be defined, the second consists of commands that change
>   the headers and/or footers, i.e. `fancyhead` etc. Also allowed are changes to `\headrulewidth` and
>   `\footrulewidth`.

I take it that you want the page numbering on `\part` and `\chapter` pages to be "fancy" as well, minus the header portion. If that's the case, the following code should work for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % is 'danish' correct?

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[lo,le]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % same placement as with page style "fancy"
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\part{Kontekstuelt}
\chapter{One}
\section{Introduction} % to make "\rightmark" non-empty
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful, works now. So, basically we need to replace that